# Get server time/count/sum (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

So basically this is what i want to do:get server time (date&time),count 24 hours backwards,go to "link",sum all "XX" within these 24 hours

Example:
current time 11:00 16.04.2013

```
16.04.2013 09:59:16 XX
16.04.2013 06:30:18 YY
16.04.2013 05:44:07 XX
15.04.2013 22:10:10 XX
15.04.2013 10:00:00 XX
```

and the function should return 3 as sum

@ Marco Forberg

```
<table class="messages-list">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="date">16.04.2013 09:59:16
</td>
<td class="text"> XX
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and current time

```
<span id="servertime" rel="1366102414">11:53:33</span>
```

Comment: why should it return 3? and could you provide more info about how your data is structured

Comment: what do you mean by structure?

Comment: what do your tables look like where the data comes from?

Comment: Oh... so all you have is an HTML table. no XML document or sql database behind it?